# medical meaning of "Meridian"

Tags: eye, terminology

A video tutorial is [using a spoon](https://youtu.be/PAdJT_GcBP4?t=39) to explain how astigmatism occurs.

> the cornea ideally
>   should be perfectly round like a
>   ping-pong ball which is a perfect sphere
>   and has the same curvature in all
>   directions astigmatism occurs when the
>   cornea is not perfectly round and has a
>   steeper and a flatter **Meridian** like the
>   back of the spoon

where the speaker uses the word "**Meridian**", does "**Meridian**" here mean "an imaginary line between the North Pole and the South Pole, drawn on maps to help to show the position of a place" or some other medical meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Meridian of the eye: Considering the center of the pupil as a pole, imaginary lines are drawn around the eyeball that is intersected at the poles (both anterior and posterior) and are called as the meridians of the eye. The flattest and steepest meridians of the eye are termed as the principal meridians.

https://www.news-medical.net/health/Astigmatism-Types-Regular-and-Irregular.aspx